# Create multiple instances of the same control with different visual properties via code-behind in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, code-behind

I am trying to prototype a GUI and created a minimal WPF project using Expression Blend 4.

I have a main window (XAML+codebehind) with eight instances of an UserControl, which is defined separately (XAML+codebehind). This user control has some containers and shapes, and I would like to have each of its instances in the main window to have a different appearance.

The idea would be to expose some properties of this control, and treat them as parameters. Then, I could use code behind to populate the main window, and for each instance I could add some hardcoded parametrizations. For example in pseudo-code:

```
first = new mycontrol;
mainwindow.maincontanier.add(first);
first.leftpanel.width = 100;
first.rightpanel.background = Gray;

second = new mycontrol;
mainwindow.maincontainer.add(second);
second.leftpanel.smalldot.stroke = Red;
second.leftpanel.insideborder.thickness = 2;

etc.
```

The problem is: I have no idea how this is usually done, so I appreciate any suggestion, specially in the form of minimally working code blocks.

Just to remember, I am doing this only as a design study, so I can compare different possible visual states of the control. I am not a C# programmer, and there is not any other GUI functionality involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to add items programatically:

```
//get mainwindow
Window main = App.Current.MainWindow;
myControl c1 = new myControl();
//change properties
myControl c2 = new myControl();
//change properties

//choose a container you want
StackPanel s = new StackPanel();

//add objects to container
s.Children.Add(c1);
s.Children.Add(c2);

//make container as your main content
main.Content = s;
```

Comment: I'll try to use it, but where should I write this code? In the MainWindow.cs? Or another file?

Comment: It's better if you write in Loaded event. In MainWindos.cs, after InitializeComponent(); line, type: "this.Loaded +=" , and press "tab" 2 times. It will create a method. Write your code in that method.

Comment: It worked. Now I am going for @NestorArturo suggestions on how to expose the usercontrol's properties and fill the `change properties` part.

Comment: You can use Data Binding feature. Here is a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bq2O5x7AdPc

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know some C# to do this. Second, your control can expose properties that map to your internals appearance properties so when the user change them, you change the equivalent inside your control.